# How to place java objects into coherence and read from coherence cache

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I am looking into coherence cache,
I need to place map object into cache.

Can any one let me know how to keep java objects into coherence cache?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as hasmap put operation.

```
import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory;
import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache;

NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("VirtualCache");

String key = "key";
HashMap value = new HashMap<String,String>();
value.put("key1","val1");
cache.put(key, value);

HashMap value = (HashMap) cache.get(key);
```

Comment: Thanks Amey for your valuable answer,   Here what is  "VirtualCache" ?

Comment: you can ignore that its given in your cache mapping `<cache-name>VirtualCache</cache-name>`, thats just a placeholder to label your cache ...  you can have it anything like "naresh-cache" :)

Comment: its the class when you use coherence in cluster, you can use alternate cache as well, check details here http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/net/NamedCache.html